# Is there a way utilizing pandas in python to input display the column name and also the datatype. Also how would is be possible to display info under

Tags: python, pandas

where employee ID is the column name and then int64 is the datatype.

employee_id: int64
Range: 1.34 - 2.07
Mean: 1.71
Standard deviation: 0.11
Median: 1.71

(this is just an example as I am new to learning the data science side of python and I want to get more organized with my code. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re looking for is df.describe() where df is your pandas dataframe. If that’s not what you’re looking for try df.info().